# asciidoctor + pygments on OS X

Tags: macos, asciidoctor

`asciidoctor` is failing me on OS X (El Capitan). I am trying to run `asciidoctor` through MacPorts.

The steps I took are:

- `sudo port install asciidoctor`. I subsequently confirm through `port installed | grep ascii` that `asciidoctor @1.5.4_0 (active)` is installed.
- `sudo port install rb-rubygems`. I now see through `port contents rb-rubygems` that the newly installed `gems` is at `/opt/local/bin/gem-1.8`.
- `sudo /opt/local/bin/gem-1.8 install pygments.rb`.

Now I run `/opt/local/bin/asciidoctor simple.adoc`:

**simple.adoc**:

```
:source-highlighter: pygments

[source,java]
Foo bar = baz + qux;
```

`asciidoctor` processes it fine, but it warns that

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: optional gem 'pygments.rb' is not installed. Functionality disabled.
```

and the Java code is not processed (fontified) by pygments.

I'll gladly settle for `coderay`. I'll also gladly settle for `/usr/local/bin/asciidoctor` (rather than the MacPorts installed one). The latter used to work, until I decided to handle more exotic languages and went for MacPorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use MacPorts. Use your ruby gem package manager instead:

```
> which gem
  /usr/local/bin/gem
> sudo gem install asciidoctor
> sudo gem install pygments.rb
```

and perhaps also:

```
> sudo gem install coderay
```

Comment: Interestingly, for me this worked by uninstalling asciidoctor and asciidoc from Homebrew, and then, by installing asciidoctor and pygments.rb via `gem`. Before that, I installed pygments via Python's pip.

Comment: Had the same problem, managed to solve uninstalling asciidoctor from Homebrew and installing it again via `gem`.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew worked for me on OS X High Sierra:

`brew install asciidoctor`